# What is the difference between machine learning and quantum machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, comparison, quantum-computing

What is the difference between machine learning and quantum machine learning?

Comment: The following questions on Quantum Computing SE [Is there any potential application of quantum computers in machine learning or AI?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1208/55), [Will deep learning neural networks run on quantum computers?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1404/55) may also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is much simpler than you might have anticipated: In the quantum computing community, machine learning algorithms designed to be used on quantum computers as opposed to classical computers, would fall under "quantum machine learning". There's really nothing more to it!

There is a short paper published in Nature called "Quantum Machine Learning" which was [mentioned before](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2152/2293), and it might give you all the answers you need about what "Quantum Machine Learning" is.

Comment: And this is different from "machine learning (on a classical computer) for quantum mechanics / quantum chemistry / quantum properties)"

Comment: @GeoffHutchison A very important distinction indeed! "Machine Learning for studying Quantum" is very different from "Quantum being used to do Machine Learning"!